# Understanding the $\delta$ - method and question about modification

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, law-of-large-numbers

$\delta$ - method says that, suppose that

$$\frac{X_n-\mu}{\sigma_n}\xrightarrow{dist.}X$$

with $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$, $0<\sigma_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $g'(\mu)\neq 0$, then

$$
\frac{g(X_n) - g(\mu)}{\sigma_n} \xrightarrow{dist.} g'(\mu)X
$$

now suppose I use the sequence of function ${g_n(x)}$ instead of $g(x)$, then what kind of modification needed to say something like usual $\delta$-method. Is there any result like that?

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1):

If you go through the proof of this result, you will see that basically it relies on the mean value theorem:

$g(X_n) - g(\mu) = g'(R_n)(X_n - \mu)$, where $R_n \in (X_n,\mu)\cup (\mu,X_n)$. In combination with $\sigma_n \to 0$, $X_n \stackrel{P}{\to} \mu$, the result comes out straightforwardly after dividing by $\sigma_n$.

If $g=g_n$, and $g_n$ is differentiable, you still have $g_n(X_n) - g_n(\mu) = g'_n(R_n)(X_n - \mu)$, so if $g_n$, $g_n'$ converge uniformly to some $g$ and $g'$, everything works out as before.

Comment: It seems implied that $g$ is differentiable, since otherwise what does $g’$ mean? Diffferentiable functions are also continuous

Comment: I'm bit wrong.  yeah you right $g$ is continuous  but you have to consider $R_n$ in open interval when you use mean value theorem. Now when you go to apply  $R_n \rightarrow \mu$ you have to consider $g'$ to be continuous, which is not given.

Comment: I fixed the intervals to be open! I just wanted to give you an example where you may take $g=g_n$, since this seemed to be what the post was asking for, and the MVT gives easy conditions to check. If you apply a general Taylor series with remainder argument you might get something more general, i.e. not requiring $g_n'$ continuous.